# DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. Error code: 0x80004005.Difference between SQl Native client and oledb provider for sql server

Tags: sql-server, oledb, ssis, dts

There was a communication link error while I was using SQL Server Native Client 10 in an SSIS Data Flow component.

> Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
>   occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "Communication link failure".An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "TCP Provider: The specified network
>   name is no longer available.

So I changed from SQL Server Native Client 10 to Microsoft OLEDB Provider for SQL Server, hoping that it would run fine. This time got an error as shown below:

> [Transacn_Tbl1[737]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE
>   DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error occurred on SQL
>   Server. Connection may have been terminated by the server.".
>
> [Transacn_Tbl1[737]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "OLE DB Destination
>   Input" (750)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the
>   error row disposition on "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (750)"
>   specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object
>   of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before
>   this with more information about the failure.

What is the difference between these 2 providers? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you  have to resolve this issue, you must change the permissions for the Temp directory of the SQL Server Agent Service startup account. Grant the Read permission and the Write permission to the SQL Server  Agent proxy account for this directory.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933835

Comment: Hi ,I was not using the sql server agent

Comment: SQL SERVER Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for <your servername>Protocols for <yourservername>> Click >TCP/IP>Double click TCP/IP> IPAddress > all Enable to “YES” > APPLY> OK

Comment: Sometimes what you have to do is save the project. Close the BIDS/SSDT and then open and try to see if there are errors. If you don't see error try to run, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks..done al these..similar question been asked by me 4months before..but nobody answered it..

Comment: Ok.. Let's troubleshoot it quick.. First delete the connection to destination, add dataviewer and see that is coming from the source. Second add the destination and add the datview and see the data is right. Before transferring the data to destination truncate the table and run the package. it should work fine

Comment: Please understand this is not a data issue..i have 1 year data to load,so i just splited it into 4 groups of 3 months data..then it works

Comment: Turn this function : Connection Manager properties > RetainSameConnection = True
It should help.

Comment: Anyone have any idea exactly HOW to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue after releasing a new `SSIS` project to the production environment.

At first, I was able to validate the package with success, but when I tried to execute the package, I got the `DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. Error code: 0x80004005.` message.

I tried to validate the package with the servername and password variables set to sensitive, but in this case the validation failed as well.

After setting the environment variables back to non-sensitive again and inserting the environment variable values, I was able to validate and execute the package.

To me it seems like in some cases the metadata in the `SSISDB` gets corrupted, but unfortunately I've not been able to point down the source of this issue.

I hope this will help someone. I've went through a lot of debug scenarios before I ended up with this (rather unsatisfying) solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005
```

This obscure error can also mean something as benign as the OLE provider cannot find the expected Excel Worksheet.

I recently came across this error in an SSIS project and after several hours trying to track down what I believed was some configuration issue, it turned out to be the end user had simply ***changed the name of a Worksheet in the Excel data source***.

> Microsoft Messaging FTW!

Answer (score 0):

I changed connection to `Provider=SQLNCLI11.1` and executed
successfully with parameters.