# SSIS error DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR when reading from a xls template with hidden row

Tags: ssis

(environment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, Version 9.03.30729, .Net Framework Version 3.5 SP1; I'm not using SQL Agent Job. )

I'm using SSIS to load data into a 1997-2003 version xls file. 
To prevent number stored as text in the destination xls file, I'm using a xls template with the 2nd row hidden. In the hidden row, I put in number and format the cell as number. For the text column, I just left them blank. 
The first task of the SSIS project is to make a copy of the template and put it in the destination folder with timestamp suffix in file name.

The project all ran ok if I use an xls template WITHOUT the hidden row. 
But once I have the hidden row, I started getting the error as pasted below.

I appreciate your feedback and suggestion. thanks!

> [Excel Destination [50]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An
>   OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>
> [Excel Destination [50]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "Excel Destination
>   Input" (61)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the
>   error row disposition on "input "Excel Destination Input" (61)"
>   specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object
>   of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before
>   this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The
>   ProcessInput method on component "Excel Destination" (50) failed with
>   error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Excel Destination Input" (61). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with
>   more information about the failure.

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603897/dts-e-oledberror-error-code-0x80004005-difference-between-sql-native-client-an

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DTS\_E\_OLEDBERROR. Error code: 0x80004005.Difference between SQl Native client and oledb provider for sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603897/dts-e-oledberror-error-code-0x80004005-difference-between-sql-native-client-an)

Comment: thank you for your comment. I'm not using SQL Server Agent. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Version 9.0.30729, with .Net Framework version 3.5 SP1

Comment: Sorry that link wasn't helpful. 
I tried to duplicate the workflow you described, and I didn't have any issues making a copy of the .xls template with hidden second row and number formatting you describe, and then using that as the destination for some sample data I came up with. Can you post more details about you source data, and show the steps you're using to create the "template" with the hidden second row? Also, if you can show your SSIS Excel destination configuration too, that would really help.